# Calling function with a varying number of arguments (JS)

Tags: javascript

Anyone knows how to do it (using ES5)? Hello.

Found similar questions in the C++ and C sections, but not in the Javascript one.

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
 
//single argument
console.log(array[0]);
 
//dynamic arguments
var item;
for (var i in array) {
 item = array[i];
 console.log("test", item);
 //same as
 //console.log("test", 0);
 //console.log("test", 1);
 //...
}

//Objective: console.log("test", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
/*var obj = {};
for (var key in array) {
 obj[key] = array[key];
}
console.log("test", obj[0], obj[1], obj[2], obj[3], obj[4]);
*/
console.log("test", array[0], array[1], array[2], array[3], array[4]);
//need to know the no. of items
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? What function need to accept varying number of arguments? What arguments list and how do it varies?

Comment: And if you just use a two dimensional array instead?

Comment: Just pass the array directly to whatever number of arguments required!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the [**spread**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) operator. It destructures your array and passes the items as separate variables.

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
 
console.log("test", ...array); // ES6 and higher
console.log.apply(console, ["test"].concat(array)); // ES5
```

Comment: If the spread operator isn't available then something like: console.log.apply(console, ["test"].concat(array))

Comment: Answer apart, I still don't know how the question made sense to you :)

Comment: Yeah; can use the ES5 version of spread: https://github.com/addyosmani/es6-equivalents-in-es5#spread-operator Thanks.

Comment: My apology; I forgot. Thanks again.